# Проверка на число JS

Tags: javascript

Сделал функцию проверки на число:

```
function isAN(value) {
  return  isFinite(value) && value === parseInt(value, 10);
}
```

Всё работает, но один тест не могу пройти:

> new Number()s
>
> ✘ isAN(new Number(1)) - Expected: true, instead got: false

Как мне добавить условие чтобы такая проверка проходила?

```
isAN(new Number(1)) // сейчас false а хочется true
```

Все тесты:

> **Strings** - *Test.assertEquals( **isAN("2")** , false*)
>
> **Booleans** - *Test.assertEquals( **isAN(true)** , false*)
>
> **Others** - *Test.assertEquals( **isAN(null)** , false*)
>
> **Numbers** - *Test.assertEquals( **isAN(2)** , true*)
>
> **new Number()s** - *Test.assertEquals( **isAN(Number(1))** , true*)
>
> **NaN Number()s** - Test.assertEquals( **isAN(NaN)**, false)

Comment: `!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)` не подходит?

Comment: вообще `isANumber = !isNaN`

Comment: А зачем? Вообще надо бы запретить `new Number`.

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin не подходит. isAN(new Number(1)) тест прошёл, но не проходят тесты: isAN("1") и isAN([1])

Comment: Добавь что ли остальные тесты, чтобы можно было хотя бы примерно проверить

Comment: По моему вы хотите плохого и ненужного. Под числом обычно понимается именно примитивное значение. Объект `Number` это не число. Хотя бы потому что `new Number(0) == new Number(0)` → `false`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen я выполняю задание с сайта, для того чтобы потренеровать свои навыки программирования. И я ограничен жесткими условиями. https://www.codewars.com/kata/

Comment: Мдя. Там даже Infinity не проверяют :(

Comment: а почему вдруг один и тот же вход, два разных результата дает? `Numbers - Test.assertEquals( isAN(2) , true)`, и ниже `NaN Number()s - Test.assertEquals( isAN(2), false)`

Comment: @Grundy Ошибка, исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Создавать ручками объект примитива - примитивизм.
Но, раз зачем-то эта возможность есть, делайте проверку:

```js
function isAN(value) {
  if(value instanceof Number)
    value = value.valueOf(); // Если это объект числа, то берём значение, которое и будет числом
  
  return  isFinite(value) && value === parseInt(value, 10);
}

console.info(isAN(1));
console.info(isAN(new Number(1)));
console.info(isAN(null));
```

Comment: `isAN({valueOf:()=>10})` → `true`. WTF?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, если объект ведет себя как число - это число

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Если объект заставляет возвращать число, то может и стоит считать его числом?

Comment: хорошая попытка. но теперь не срабатывает проверка на null ^TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueOf' of null

Comment: @stas0k, да, забыл о этом глюке JS (что тип `null` - объект). Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Ну не уверен. У него нет методов числа. `a = {valueOf:()=>0};`. `!a` → `false`. (Так же как и `new Number(0)`). В общем, я бы не стал пользоваться такой проверкой на число.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, если кто-то пытается притворится числом, то должен позаботиться о методах и прочем. Но переделал под Ваши пожелания. Так даже лучше, наверное.

Answer (score 2):

А почему не использовать связку с parseInt или parseFloat:
    `if(parseInt(value) >= 0 || parseInt(value) <= 0)`

Все тесты проходит.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function isAN(value) {
  return (value instanceof Number||typeof value === 'number') && !isNaN(value);
}

console.info(isAN(1));
console.info(isAN(new Number(1)));
console.info(isAN(null));
console.info(isAN("1"));
console.info(isAN(true));
```

Answer (score 1):

`function isAN(value) { return +value; }`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

юзай без new, вместе с new получается объект обертка

`isAN(Number(1))` //  true

Comment: Данный вызов происходит в тесте, к которому автор вопроса не имеет доступа